# how to autogenerate transaction ID during checkout in Opencart?

Tags: e-commerce, opencart, checkout

I am trying to integrate a payment gateway (www.sslcommerz.com.bd) in Opencart  which requires to submit a transaction id at the time of checkout. This transaction id needs to be stored in the database and The gateway will save the Transaction ID for any sort of future queries and cross checking with online store system for verification of payment completion. I am new to Opencart. can anyone please give some idea how should I approach to achieve that? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at any one of the other modifications for payment gateways in your version(s). PayPal Standard is most likely the best option. You will see that the order ID is set in a session variable as it is generated by the checkout and can be accessed in your payment gateways' template file/through the controller file. The session variable is

```
$this->session->data['order_id']
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. Yes, I also found out that using order_id is a good idea. Now that raises another question in my mind. If I have multiple stores, transaction id will not remain unique any more.what can I do in this situation?

Comment: In that situation, I would recommend hashing the store URL with the transaction ID, giving a unique hash per transaction

Comment: In that case, I need to store it in database as an additional field. I am sorry if I bother you much, is there any default function/method for adding custom order record in opencart?

Comment: It's the addOrder method that returns the new order id in `/catalog/model/checkout/order.php`